# mysql/php merging/combining row values

Tags: php, mysql

I am having a problem with an select statement. When im using distinct it will still give me duplicate of certain rows. I have tried using group by it fixed the duplication but it deleted one of the values.

Links to Image:
[Group by and Distinct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mn0v3.jpg)

this is what i want it to output:
[Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OfQyO.jpg)

this is my code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT M.Major, 
       S.Ethnicity = 'American Indian or Alaska Native' AS AIAN,
       S.Ethnicity = 'Asian' AS Asian,
       S.Ethnicity = 'Black or African American' AS Black,
       S.Ethnicity = 'Hispanic/Latino' AS Hisp,
       S.Ethnicity = 'Native Hawaiian or Other Pacific Islander' AS Native,
       S.Ethnicity = 'White' AS White,
       S.Ethnicity = 'Unknown/Other' As Other
FROM STUDENT AS S, MAJOR AS M
WHERE S.Major_ID = M.MajorID and S.Gender = 'Female'
Group By M.Major;

STUDENT | 
   CREATE TABLE `STUDENT` (
  `StudentID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `FirstName` char(35) NOT NULL,
  `LastName` char(35) NOT NULL,
  `DateOfBirth` date NOT NULL,
  `SSN` char(11) NOT NULL,
  `GGCEmail` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `Gender` char(6) NOT NULL,
  `Ethnicity` char(100) NOT NULL,
  `IsGrad` char(3) NOT NULL,
  `Major_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Minor_ID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE   CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`StudentID`),
  KEY `MAJOR_STUDENT_FK` (`Major_ID`),
  KEY `MINOR_STUDENT_FK` (`Minor_ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `MAJOR_STUDENT_FK` FOREIGN KEY (`Major_ID`) REFERENCES `MAJOR` (`MajorID`),
  CONSTRAINT `MINOR_STUDENT_FK` FOREIGN KEY (`Minor_ID`) REFERENCES `MINOR` (`MinorID`)

MAJOR | 
CREATE TABLE `MAJOR` (
  `MajorID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Major` char(100) NOT NULL,
  `EntryGPA` decimal(3,2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`MajorID`)
```

Comment: please show your student and major  table  schema

Comment: Seems you have a wrong sintax .. .. S.Ethnicity = 'American Indian or Alaska Native' AS  ... the = after S.Ethnicity  what mean ? I never see this sintax

Comment: posted the schema, Im using the S.Ethnicity = '___ ' to count each ethnicity in a certain major.

Comment: The sintax S.Ethnicity = don't give you the count in but only set to 1 if match.. is that what you need ?

Comment: if you need it to count instead of `S.Ethnicty = '___' AS name`, do `SUM(S.Ethnicity = '___') AS name` then do `GROUP BY M.Major`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use a sum and select case

```
    SELECT DISTINCT M.Major, 
        sum( case S.Ethnicity when 'American Indian or Alaska Native' then 1 else 0 END)  AS AIAN,
        sum( case S.Ethnicity when 'Asian' then 1 else 0 END ) AS Asian,
        sum( case S.Ethnicity when 'Black or African American' then 1 else 0 END ) AS Black,
        sum( case S.Ethnicity when 'Hispanic/Latino' then 1 else 0 END) AS Hisp,
        sum( case S.Ethnicity when 'Native Hawaiian or Other Pacific Islander' then 1 else 0 END) AS Native,
        sum( case S.Ethnicity when 'White' then 1 else 0 END) AS White,
        sum( case S.Ethnicity when 'Unknown/Other' then 1 else 0 END) As Other
    FROM STUDENT AS S, MAJOR AS M
    WHERE S.Major_ID = M.MajorID and S.Gender = 'Female'
    Group By M.Major;
```

Comment: For this code i am getting an error: ERROR 1630 (42000): FUNCTION DB.sum does not exist. Check the 'Function Name Parsing and Resolution' section in the Reference Manual

Comment: There are two space between sum and (  .. i have removed  .. i have update the answer

Comment: If you dont mind. can you explain the concept of using the sum and select case?

Comment: Sure .. In your case you want select form the same column (Ethnicity)  a set of different result based on the content fo these field, also for each matching value  you need count +1 .. then with select case the single column in splitter in the diffrent column responding 1 when the value of the field match 0 if not ... and last .. sum() all this values  give you the desired result ... hope this explanation is clear ...

Comment: ok. so its basically like java if else statement. if(meet condition) +1 else +0;

Comment: in this case yes ... but is used for multiple contition too